# find path of files from a list of filenames and display it

Tags: shell

I have a file named "file.txt" which contains several filenames like this :

```
filename1.ext
filename2.ext
filename3.ext
filename4.ext
```

I want to find these files through the directory /home (And so all the sub-directories of the directory etc etc..) [I assume I will have to use the find command from the shell], display the name of the file if the directory contains it and the associated path.

The file "file.txt" will be passed as an argument so the command should be ./find_path.sh file.txt

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is of the form: "Please write code to solve this trivial problem"

Answer (score 0):

I would do this: build up an array holding the arguments you give to `find`

```sh
find_args=("-false")
while read -r file; do
    find_args+=("-o" "-name" "$file"); 
done < "$1"
find /home "${find_args[@]}"
```

That gives you the flexibility to add further directives, for example if you want to change the output:

```sh
find /home "${find_args[@]}" -printf '%f\t%h\n' | sort -k 1,1
```